# Is this ruby(rails) code readable simply?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First

```
[1] pry(main)> 1.month.from_now.change(%i(min sec).inject({}){|h, i| h.merge(i => Time.current.send(i))}.merge(hour: 10))
=> Sat, 03 Aug 2019 10:25:00 KST +09:00
```

Second

```
[2] pry(main)> 1.month.from_now.change(min: Time.current.min, sec: Time.current.sec, hour: 10)
=> Sat, 03 Aug 2019 10:26:31 KST +09:00
```

Which code is more readable?

I think first code is less simple to read.

First code be can separated two part.

`1.month.from_now.change` - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-change

```
[3] pry(main)> %i(min sec).inject({}){ |h, i| # https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject
[3] pry(main)*   h.merge(i => Time.current.send(i)) # https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send
[3] pry(main)* }.merge(hour: 10)
=> {:min=>34, :sec=>48, :hour=>10}
```

So when someone who is unfamiliar with ruby read first code, little bit difficult.

By the way, if someone know `Time.change` method, second code is more simple.

The difference is first code is less repetitive than second.

1. Time.current
2. min
3. sec

First code is use only once above keyword. So first code use additional `inject` method and `merge` method, and additional complexity.

What I use the code?

Comment: Wt'heck is going on here :P

Comment: You might get better traffic on this question on the codereview.stackexchange.com, (I threw an answer up anyways)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd version is easier to read. Here's a few other things that might help

- Putting the current time in a variable so you're calling `1.month.from_now`, and your `min` and `sec` arguments using the same time
- Putting the time adjustments in logical reading order (hours, minutes, seconds)
- Chaining with `advance` makes this slightly more readable, I think

Example:

```
today = Time.current
next_month = today.
  advance(months: 1).
  change(hour: 10, min: today.min, sec: today.sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second code is absolutely more readable than the first one. Its also seems easier to get that first one.